# How to Pass -X Switch to SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild?

Tags: sonarqube-msbuild-runner, sonarqube5.2

Log message states

```
`ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.`
```

How do I pass -X switch to Sonar Runner from MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe. Is it in the `begin` command or `end` command?

My search is not yielding an answer for this how-to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When make the call for the SonarQube runner add the following parameter:

```
/d:sonar.verbose=true
```